# change Lightworks folder [Linux]

Tags: linux, lightworks

I've installed **Lightworks** Free on Linux Debian.

When execute, it generates a `Lightworks` directory in `/home/USER`.

After move it to another directory where got all the programs, and execute it again, it keeps generating the previous folder on the same place.

How can change it to a preferred location?

Comment: Do you have the Free or Pro version?

Comment: Thx for answer. The free version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the product comparison source](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=102&Itemid=213), the free version does not allow to "User definable project locations". This is only possible for the Pro version.